# Is there information somewhere on Swift protocol associatedtype using `=` versus `:`?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, generics, associated-types

I'm trying to find out if there's any documentation on Swift's protocol `associatedtype` using a `=` instead of a `:`.

Eg.
`associatedtype Thing = SomeOtherThing`
vs
`associatedtype Thing: SomeOtherThing`

Not to be confused with (what probably confused me) `typealias Thing = SomeOtherThing` which is always a `=` I believe.

I was trying to abstract usage of a class that included a delegate and was using `=` for `associatedtype`s until I ran into an issue where the variable that was that type wasn't exposing its properties due to the `=` and instead needed the usual `:`, which to me made sense, in a way, but then when I changed one particular `=` to a `:` it caused everything to break. I've included an example below, where the idea was to be able to get/set the delegate object freely, but more or less one protocol was saying that it's delegate must be the type of the associated type (with the `=`) rather than just "you must conform to this" as the `:` seems to suggest.

I also don't know if I've taken this one step too far and there's some other better way to express this in terms of testing. This seems to be required as I can't exactly rely on the external object to work as expected in the tests, and instead need to mock it to fail on purpose and such in some cases.

```swift
import Foundation

// Concrete objects (eg external framework)

protocol ManagerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func managerDidSomething(_ manager: Manager)
}

class Manager {
    weak var delegate: ManagerDelegate?
    func doSomething() {
        delegate?.managerDidSomething(self)
    }
}

// Custom objects using concrete objects, set up to be testable

class CustomManagerDelegate: ManagerDelegate {
    func managerDidSomething(_ manager: Manager) {
        print(#function)
    }
}

class CustomClass<ManagerType: SomeManager> {
    
    private(set) var doSomethingCustomCalled = false
    
    private let managerDelegate: ManagerType.DelegateType
    private let manager: ManagerType
    
    init(manager: ManagerType, managerDelegate: ManagerType.DelegateType) {
        self.manager = manager
        self.managerDelegate = managerDelegate
        manager.delegate = managerDelegate
    }
    
    func doSomethingCustom() {
        doSomethingCustomCalled = true
        manager.doSomething()
    }
    
}

// Example creation of custom object

class Example {
    
    static func createCustomObject() {
        let customObject = CustomClass(
            manager: Manager(),
            // if `:` used instead of `=` for `SomeManager.DelegateType`, error is:
            // Cannot convert value of type 'CustomManagerDelegate' to expected argument type 'Manager.DelegateType'
            managerDelegate: CustomManagerDelegate() // error fix: add `as! Manager.DelegateType`
        )
        customObject.doSomethingCustom()
    }
    
}

// Testable interface

protocol SomeManager: AnyObject {
    // This `=` is the only thing keeping it together
    associatedtype DelegateType = SomeManagerDelegate
    // This doesn't work
    //associatedtype DelegateType: SomeManagerDelegate
    var delegate: DelegateType? { get set }
    func doSomething()
}

protocol SomeManagerDelegate {
    associatedtype ManagerType: SomeManager
    func managerDidSomething(_ manager: ManagerType)
}

// Testable interface conformance

// if `:` used instead of `=` for `SomeManager.DelegateType`, error is:
// Type 'Manager' does not conform to protocol 'SomeManager'
extension Manager: SomeManager {
    // already conforms
}

class MockManagerDelegate: SomeManagerDelegate {
    
    typealias ManagerType = MockManager
    
    func managerDidSomething(_ manager: ManagerType) {
        print(#function)
    }
    
}

class MockManager: SomeManager {
    
    weak var delegate: MockManagerDelegate?
    
    func doSomething() {
        delegate?.managerDidSomething(self)
    }
    
}

// Tests

class CustomClassTests {
    
    func testCustomSomethingWasCalled() {
        let mockInjectedCustomClass = CustomClass(
            manager: MockManager(),
            managerDelegate: MockManagerDelegate()
        )
        mockInjectedCustomClass.doSomethingCustom()
        print("Was Called:", mockInjectedCustomClass.doSomethingCustomCalled)
        assert(mockInjectedCustomClass.doSomethingCustomCalled)
    }
    
}

CustomClassTests().testCustomSomethingWasCalled()

/* console:
 managerDidSomething(_:)
 Was Called: true
 */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `=` and the `:` are two independent parts of an associated type declaration, rather than being mutually exclusive. This is the full syntax of [protocol associated type declaration](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#grammar_protocol-associated-type-declaration):

```
attributes(opt) 
access-level-modifier(opt) 
'associatedtype' 
typealias-name 
type-inheritance-clause(opt) 
typealias-assignment(opt) 
generic-where-clause(opt)
```

The `: TypeName` part is the `type-inheritance-clause`, and the `= TypeName` is the `typealias-assignment`.

`: TypeName` constrains what type the associated type can be, namely that it must inherit/conform to `TypeName`. This is why `: SomeManagerDelegate` didn't work in your case. You are saying that `SomeManager.DelegateType` must be some kind of `SomeManagerDelegate`, but for `Manager`, this is not true - `Manager.delegate` is of type `ManagerDelegate`, which is a totally unrelated protocol. Even if it were `SomeManagerDelegate`, it wouldn't work either because [protocols don't conform to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself).

`= TypeName` sets a default type for the associated type. If the compiler cannot infer what the type the associated type for a conformance should be and you didn't say it explicitly it either, it will use that type instead. But in your case, this fact didn't really matter. What actually caused your code to work, wasn't the *addition* of `= SomeManagerDelegate`, but the *removal* of the constraint `: SomeManagerDelegate`. You are no longer constraining what type the associated type should be (it can be anything!), so for `Manager`, the associated type can now be inferred to be `ManagerDelegate`. Note that you don't have to explicitly say:

```
typealias DelegateType = ManagerDelegate
```

In fact, you can totally remove `= SomeManagerDelegate` and just say:

```
associatedtype DelegateType
```

so it is far from the truth that the `=` is "the only thing keeping it together".

This `= TypeName` syntax doesn't seem [very well documented](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8761). Here's a related [Swift forums post](https://forums.swift.org/t/a-question-about-associatedtype-in-protocols/16168).

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the info and related links/docs. And yep, you're not wrong about being able to total remove the `= SomeManagerDelegate`, so that's interesting in itself 